# Listview - menu for switching item

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, listview

I'd like to add an option to my ListView, so that I can change it's view (tile, list, details,...) - just like in Windows Explorer. How can I build such a menu? With PictureBox and MenuStrip?

[alt text http://img689.imageshack.us/img689/6792/temprt.jpg](http://img689.imageshack.us/img689/6792/temprt.jpg)

PS: winforms, not WPF

Thanks!

Comment: Winforms, editem my question.

Comment: You should choose an answer, and I would assume you would choose your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How I did it:

1. I created new user control and added a button with this icon.
2. Then I added ContextMenu with all five items.
3. Button.OnClick shows ContextMenu
4. Added public event for ItemClicked with parameter View
5. Added public property for selected view

Answer (score 1):

Set its ContextMenuStrip property.  Choosing Details does require you to add Columns.